# set the SimpleCursorAdapter depending on the API version of the phone?

Tags: android

i have a android app which uses the `SimpleCursorAdapter`

i have the min `API level 9`
when i want to use the `SimpleCursorAdapter` i use the following constructor:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to)
```

but then i get the message that this is **deprecated**.

so i change it to the newer version:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags)
```

but then my min API level should be 11 but i dont want to change it.

**is it possible to let android check the version like: if api level >= 11 use the new one, else use the old?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [SimpleCursorAdapter from the support class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html). It is used like the API 11+ version and it is already backwards compatible.

Odds are you already downloaded the Support Library (if you haven't you *really* should), so you only need to change the import:

```
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (Android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE==Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
...
} else {
...
}
```